# JDBC connection problems

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to use the jdbc driver for Microsoft SQL server to connect to my database i manage to establish a connection with the server, however some weird stuff happens. Here is my Dconnector class:

```
package com.myblog;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Dconnector {
public Connection connection = null;
public Statement stmt;
static Properties prop = null;
public Dconnector() throws SQLException {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new SQLServerDriver());
    System.out.println("SQL JDBC Connection Testing");
    prop = new Properties();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String DB_CONN_STRING = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=blogdb;";
        //Provided by your driver documentation. In this case, a MySql driver is used :
        String USER_NAME = "sa";
        String PASSWORD = "pwd";
        connection =DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONN_STRING, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("Connected!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect!");
    }

}

public ResultSet queryResult(String Query) {
    ResultSet rst = null;
    try {
        rst = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rst;
}

public int queryCount(String Query) {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        count = stmt.executeUpdate(Query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return count;
}
public void closeConnection()
{
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

What is weird is that when i launch the web app and create a new instance of Dconnector like so:

```
com.myblog.Dconnector db=new com.myblog.Dconnector();
```

And close it with:

```
db.closeConnection();
```

For some reason it seems that the class is instatiated 3 times? In console the "SQL JDBC Connection Testing" followed by "Connected!" is displayed 3 times.

Also when I try to call the queryResult with any query in between the connection opening and closing all hell breaks loose with Error reading prelogin response and connection resets repeated again 3 times.

Here is the code used in the .jsp file (the scriplet):

```
com.myblog.Dconnector db=new com.myblog.Dconnector();
  ResultSet rst=db.queryResult("SELECT Caption FROM ArticlesTB");
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rst.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
  try {
      while (rst.next()) {
          for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
              String columnValue = rst.getString(i);
              System.out.print("<h1>" +columnValue + " 
    </h1>"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          }


  }}
  catch (SQLException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("This did not work");
  }

db.closeConnection();
```

I am just outputting to console for now for testing. The relevant part of the console output is following:

```
Connected to server
[2018-09-05 11:53:39,507] Artifact Stranka:war exploded: Artifact is being 
deployed, please wait...
05-Sep-2018 23:53:40.372 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned 
for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a 
complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. 
Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP 
compilation time.
[2018-09-05 11:53:40,435] Artifact Stranka:war exploded: Artifact is deployed 
successfully
[2018-09-05 11:53:40,435] Artifact Stranka:war exploded: Deploy took 928 
milliseconds
-------- SQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
You made it, take control your database now!
(h1)This is a sample article(/h1)
(h1)This is a second article.(/h1)
(h1)This is a third sample.(/h1)
-------- SQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
You made it, take control your database now!
(h1)This is a sample article(/h1)
(h1)This is a second article.(/h1)
(h1)This is a third sample.(/h1)
-------- SQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
You made it, take control your database now!
(h1)This is a sample article(/h1)
(h1)This is a second article.(/h1)
(h1)This is a third sample.(/h1)
05-Sep-2018 23:53:49.219 INFO 
[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web 
application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.11\webapps\manager]
05-Sep-2018 23:53:49.312 INFO 
[ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web 
application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.11\webapps\manager] has finished 
in [93] ms
```

HTML tags were edited to maintain code format.

Comment: Your problem is likely in the code calling the various methods of the `Dconnector` class, so you need to show us that code, in order for us to help you. E.g. my *guess* is that you see those messages 3 times because you actually create 3 different instances of the class, but without seeing the code, that's just an educated guess.

Comment: That is a good point, thank you. I will add the calling code into the original post right away. I simply do not see the reason why would the class be instantiated 3 times, but surely the fault is on my side since this is my first real JAVA app.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` when you can call [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)? Why do either of those when you can call [`System.out.println(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I find it weird that your code, which presumably is in a JSP, is executed during the *deployment* of the .war file. JSPs are only executed when the a web request needs the JSP for rendering the output.

Comment: Well this jsp is an index in a web application project, maybe thats why? I honestly dont know. About the new line, I did not know about System.lineSeparator, anyway in the final product I will be using out.print and HTML/CSS for indentation and new lines. It just did it this way to better see what exactly and when is printed. The weird thing is that it only prints three times into the console. When all I did was change System.out.print to out.print the resulting page is in order without any duplicated (triplicates). However the connection success message in console still appears 3 times.

Comment: At this point this honestly is not a big problem since it does not impact functionality. however it is still weird.